# Database design confusion

Tags: mysql, database, classification

I'm developing a classifieds site. And I'm totally stuck at database design level.
Advertisiment can only be in 1 category.
In my database I have table called "ads", which has columns, common for all advertisements.

```
CREATE TABLE Ads (
AdID int not null,
AdDate datetime not null,
AdCategory int not null,
AdHeading varchar(255) not null,
AdText varchar(255) not null,
etc...
);
```

I also have a lot of categories.
Ads that are posted in "cars" category, for example, have additional columns like make, model, color, etc. Ads, posted in "housing" have columns like housing type, sqft. etc...
I did something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
AdID int not null,
CarMake varchar (255) not null,
CarModel varchar(255) not null,
...
);

CREATE TABLE Housing (
AdID int not null,
HousingType varchar (255) not null
...
);
```

AdId in those is a foreign key to Ads.

But when I need to retrieve information from Ads, I have to look up all those additional tables and check if AdId in Ads equals to AdId in those tables.
For every category I need a new table. I'm gonna end up with like 15 tables or so.
I had an idea to have a boolean columns in Ads table like is_Cars, is_Housing, etc but having a 15 columns, where 14 would be NULL seems to be horrible.
Is there any better way to design this database? I need my database to be in a 3rd normal form, this is the most important requirement.

Comment: If you know the categories from the start - why not have 15 tables? There are databases having hundreds of tables.

Comment: Have a look at [design-parts-db](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180758/)

Comment: Thank you for useful link. I am a little bit worried because it's my first project using SQL. It looks like making 15 tables probably is the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry too much - it's a well known dilemma, there are no 'silver bullets' and all solutions have some trade-offs. Your solution sounds good to me, and is commonly used in the industry. On the down side it has JOINS as you mentioned (**which is a well-known trade-off of normalization** anyway), and also each new product type requires a new TABLE. On the up side the table structure precisely reflects your business logic, it's readable and efficient in storage.

Your other suggestion, as far as I understand, was a single table where each row has a "type" indication - car, house etc (btw no need for multiple columns such as 'is_car', 'is_house' - it's simpler to have a single column 'type', e.g. type=1 indicates car, type=2 indicates house etc). Then multiple columns where some of them are unused for some product types.
Well, here the advantage is capability to add new types dynamically (even user-defined types) without changing the database schema. Also no 'JOINs'. On the down side you'll be storing & retrieving lots of 'null' cells, and also the schema would be less descriptive: e.g. it's harder to put a constraint "carModel column is not nullable", because it is nullable for houses (you can use triggers, but it's less readable).

Personally I prefer the 1st solution (of course depending on the usecase, but the 1st solution is my first instinct). And I can use it with some peace of mind after considering the trade-offs, e.g. understanding that I'm tolerating those JOINS as payment for a readable & compact schema.

Answer (score 0):

One, you are confusing categories and product specifications.

Two, you need to read up on Table Inheritance.

If you don't mind nulls, use Single Table Inheritance. All "categories" (cars, houses, ...) go in one table and have a "type" column.

If you don't like nulls, use Class Table Inheritance. Make a master table with the primary keys that you point your category foreign key at. Make child tables for each type (cars, houses, ...) whose primary key is also a foreign key to the master table. This is easier with an ORM like Hibernate.

Comment: If I use class table inheritance, it will be in 3rd normal form?

Comment: @user3660090 That would depend on the rest of your modeling, but it would be normalized, yes